# How can i test a angular page with dynamically created form elements using protractor.?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a html for created using ng-repeat which contains elements of three types.
The types are checkbox,radio,text. I'am  enabling elements created in form using custom logic based on the value of selected element. For example: when a   radio button value is choose i show a textbox element and so on. i need to test this dynamic logic using porotractor.Please suggest me some method to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Protractor to select the radio button element and click on it. You can then check the visibility of the text box element.

See http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click.

Comment: Actually the logic is dynamic. That means each time protractor loads the form page,a random form is generated with a different logic. Hence we are not sure that radio button element will be enabling text box.

Comment: Does that mean you don't know what input type is going to be created?

Comment: Actually yes.The inputs are created based on logic set on current input. It may vary with each form.

Comment: And do you know the behaviour of each input type?